# Ошибка при запуске бота

Tags: python, discord.py

Я сделал бота, раньше все хорошо работало, а теперь при запуске вылетает ошибка, но не на что не влияет:

```
[2022-08-23 16:43:52] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2022-08-23 16:43:52] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway
```

Не знаю какой участок кода скинуть, у меня там 1200 строк, сюда не влезет. Что это может быть?

Comment: А где вы тут ошибку увидели? INFO - это просто информация от библиотеки, если её не было раньше, то возможно просто разработчики добавили её с обновлением.

Comment: Да, похоже на то, заметил обновление, спасибо